# “Shirk” VS “Get out of doing something”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, phrasal-verbs

> - You have left the shop and didn’t care what would happen to your business just for having some fun and hanging out with those guys!
>   We have bigger fishes to fry son.
>   We must pay the installments back on the loan we’ve taken out from the bank and plan for opening new branches! 
>   Look; If you ............ your responsibilities/duties now, the situation will just be that much harder to deal with next month.

**a)** [shirk](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/shirk) 
**b)** [get out of doing](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+out+of+doing+(something))

As you can see in my provided links, both options mean the same to a non-native one like me!
I was wondering how they differ in meaning if they do. Otherwise, please let me know if they are interchangeable in this sense.

Comment: The link at (b) is to _get out of_, without _doing_. You don't 'do responsibilities'. Also, I think 'get out of' is more appropriate with reference to a single task than to duties in general. 'Shirk' is a better choice here.

Comment: Post edited @Kate Bounting. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: If you're bothered about using ***shirk*** because it's a relatively uncommon / "upmarket" word, consider alternatives such as ***duck, dodge***. Note that ***to get out of** something* often implies taking more "active" measures to avoid doing one's duty than simply *shirking, ducking, dodging* (all of which can simply imply "passively" failing to volunteer, for example - where *getting out of it* might more strongly imply "actively" coming up with excuses / justifications for one's inaction).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers. That was a quite helpful comment on this post.